# what's the meaning of "X Continuous Integration：xxx/xxx"?

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using melodic and Gazebo 9, and I am learning ros_control.

My question is, what does the "X Continuous Integration：xxx/xxx" mean? such as "X Continuous Integration：242/249" in   [ros_controllers](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_controllers) in melodic, does it mean that I can't use the ros_controllers in melodic?

thanks！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331956/what%27s-the-meaning-of-%22x-continuous-integration%EF%BC%9Axxx/xxx%22?/) by [Panason](https://answers.ros.org/users/44410/panason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a practical perspective, a package that is released but has failing tests can be installed and will probably build, but the test failures indicate that the package probably has bugs.

You will need to review the test failures to determine whether the failing tests indicate bugs that will be a problem for you or not. For example, if you're not trying to use the libraries or controllers where the tests are failing, then the package will probably work OK.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panason](https://answers.ros.org/users/44410/panason/) on 2019-08-29**:
thanks！

[1]  The melodic ros_controllers Package has released, but test failure, so will it fix the error and bug in the immediate future?

[2]  I have installed the ros_controllers Package in my ubuntu, how to update the Package when bug fixed?

thanks!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-08-30**:
(1) if the test failures indicate a bug that you care about, you should ask the maintainers about them, and maybe offer to help fix them. The maintainers may not be aware of the test failures, or may not have time to  work on them.

(2) When the bug is fixed and the maintainer releases a new version of the package, it will be uploaded to apt during the next ROS package sync. Then you will get it automatically the next time you run `apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [ROS Wiki: announcing extended CI badges in package headers](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-wiki-announcing-extended-ci-badges-in-package-headers/4930) on ROS Discourse for the announcement about those CI badges.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panason](https://answers.ros.org/users/44410/panason/) on 2019-08-29**:
thanks！

[1]  The melodic ros_controllers Package has released, but test failure, so will it fix the error and bug in the immediate future?

[2]  I have installed the ros_controllers Package in my ubuntu, how to update the Package when bug fixed?

thanks!